# How to resolve a pom in the dependencies list?

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am very new to Maven and am trying to use it to load the JARs I need for a web project.

I have been using the goal `dependency:copy-dependencies` and have set the output path to `<project>\WEB-INF\libs`. This has worked well so far.

I now want to intergrate the latest version of Swagger which has the following POM:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-project -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

All this does is to load the POM to the libs folder.

Is it possible to recursively resolve POMs in the dependencies list or have I misunderstood something basic?

Comment: I think you want to integrate the swagger jars and not the pom of the swagger project.

https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cio.swagger.core.v3

Comment: so I need to read the swagger pom myself and determine what modules are contained? I had hoped it might be done automatically...

Comment: You should determine what dependencies you need for your work and add these dependencies to your pom

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comment, take out the pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-project -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-rc4</version>
</dependency>
```

The default type is jar so you don't need it, other types are pom, war, ear.

Make sure you have [your proxy](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) set in your settings.xml, which should be in ~/.m2 directory.

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but I got an error. However, it might be a communications error (firewall) I'll check more closely